# error in installing library(geojsonio) R programming

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to install `library(geojsonio)` in R but I am getting this error

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘geojsonio’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): there is no package called ‘foreign’

Comment: Have you already run install.packages("geojsonio") ?

Comment: Have you run `install.packages("foreign")`?

Comment: yes already did that @BillO'Brien

Comment: install.packages("foreign")
``` Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘foreign’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)``` @Peter

Comment: It looks as if you may be using an earlier version of R: check with `R.Version()` I think R is on version 4.1.3 now so it might be necessary to update your R installation.

Comment: @Peter Is it a requirement of `geojsonio` package to use the latest version of `R`?
I am running my code in Dataiku and I don't have the permission to upgrade the `R` my organization uses; so I am stuck with version `3.6`.

Comment: From the package documentation `geojsonio` should function with `R>=3.5` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geojsonio/index.html. I am not familiar with Dataiku. My comments are really a general response to the error message(s) rather than a known solution to the specific errors - sorry I cannot be more helpful.